# How matter waves travel faster than light?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, faster-than-light, textbook-erratum

I read this in my physics textbook. It says that matter waves travel faster than light. Why is it so?

Also are matter waves G-Waves?

[image: textbook reference]

Comment: @ShubhamWagh Based on the excerpt you posted, your book is _very_ bad. Try buying one of the standard books used in an American physics class instead.

Comment: @knzhou Umm ok  thanks BTW its given by our state board council in India, no wonders now!

Comment: @ShubhamWagh Yeah, I'm sorry. We get a lot of questions from Indians who use their state-approved books, and it's always a problem with the book, not the student.

Comment: @Qmechanic HSC textbook standard 12th Maharashtra page no 302

Comment: Thumbs Up - Light is bent by Gravity, surely the medium light travels is the same Gravity propagates, viscosity of the medium may vary, but Light is subdued by Gravity we know to be true! Light Speed is a constant for Light, not for Gravity, Black holes absorb Light, a -Negative Mass where Light can not escape, a fundamental flaw, the postulate that is mostly true... most of the time, time is another problem in itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I read this thing in my physics textbook.They said matter waves travel faster than light, why is it so?

Matter waves is a confusing terminology coming from the [de Broglie](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/debrog2.html) quantum mechanical description of particles, which is what matter is at the quantum mechanical level.

[image: de broglie]

Here lamda is the wavelength of the **probability distribution** that gives the probable location of the particle in space , when it is measured. It is not the particle that is waving, i.e. changing sinusoidaly in space and time, but the *probability* of finding it at that (x,y,z,t).

[Special relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_relativity) imposes the limit of the velocity of light on any motion of particles, in all frameworks, classical and quantum mechanical.

Thus there is no way the statement as you have written is correct, unless there is some reference to the [phase velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_velocity)  which can be different for light (classical framework) in a medium. For a particle it would again refer to the probability distribution and will be a non measurable quantity, just a mathematical description.

> Also matter waves Are G-Waves?

No , they are probability waves of particles in the quantum mechanical framework, the underlying framework of nature. G waves are [gravitational waves.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_wave) There also exist [gravity waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_wave), but that is another story.

Just saw your edit. **The statement "matter waves travel faster than light"  as written in the book is wrong**. Period.

Comment: Well, the statement of the de Broglie wavelength in the book is correct in the low-velocity regime. Since this book looks to be covering non-relativsitic QM only, I don't see a problem with this approximation. So the statement is **not** "wrong. Period"; rather, it's an approximation that is widely used in introductory texts.

Comment: @probably_someone  I am talking about the "faster than light" which was the question. edited in the wrong statement

Comment: @probably_someone (which is also a wrong statement, cool but pure nonsense), Anna is totally right. Lambda = h/p is right, and p can be infinite (i.e., has no limit in physics), but p is not mv in special relativity, and v cannot be faster than c. No exceptions. As Anna said, the book is wrong. Special relativity and QM live together quite consistently.  Saying that something can go faster than light is not excusable by saying it's an approximation. You'd say probably but it's more like certainly. And the answer by JMLCarter is also wrong, certainly

Comment: Not related to this question but for my own info:  what about galaxies at the out edges of the observable universe?  It was stated on this site that they were receding from us at well over the speed of light.  Just curious how this is viewed.

Comment: What happens when there are answers totally opposite from each other like here?  I often review answers to better understand certain issues.  This is one such case.  These competing answers only serve to confuse me even more! lol..  And I was pretty confused to begin with..

Comment: @john there is no conflict with Bruce's answer. He is trying to explain how such a misstatement has arisen. The Schrodinger equation is non-relativistic, i.e. does not obey Lorenz invariance which imposes constancy of light velocity and a limit to the velocity of information transfer. That is why the Dirac equation and the Klein Gordon one etc were developed, to include the constraints of relativity.

Comment: It is the space that is expanding with velocities larger than c, and no information can be transferred between those galaxies and us. It is the possibility of interacting that is limited by the velocity c. It may help you understand the difference if you consider shining a laser on the moon . The laser spot can be seen to move faster than light, but it is not a usable knowledgefor people on the moon. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lighthouse_paradox#Similar_Moon_paradox

Comment: Thanks Anna.  I get what you are saying.  I'll just have to sort it all out.

Comment: @anna v I'm reading all this answers and everything seems conflicting. The phase velocity is the velocity with which the wave (which is here just a mathematical description, its amplitude is not a physically measurable quantity, as you said) propagates, so, as such, the statement that the matter wave (i.e. the de Broglie wave i.e. a description of probability) travels faster than light would indeed be correct under mathematical rigour, because maths doesn't impose any limit on such a wave function. Please, tell me how I'm wrong.

Comment: @StefanOctavian  The de Broglie wave is part of a primitive model, proposed when quantum mechanics was in its infancy and  special relativity was not imposed on the models. Quantum mechanics defines the wave as a **probability** of finding a particle with that "wavelength" at (x,y,z,t) . see this one electron at a time experiment that when many electrons overlap shows the wave dependence : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Interference_of_individual_particles  . The limit of c velocity of light comes from special relativity in the correct mathematics that we use now

Comment: I still don't see the point. Have the relations corresponding to (or defining) the de Broglie wave: $\lambda = h/p, \nu = mc^2/h$ changed? I mean, since you say that quantum mechanics now defines the wave as a probability (distribution I think?), and the formulas are the same ($p$ and $m$ are the relativistic momentum and mass), and since the relation $v_B = c^2/v$ follows directly from the de Broglie relations, and since we are working with a mathematical device mostly, I don't see how any limit can be put on the phase velocity (or just "the velocity") of the wave.

Comment: You are putting the cart before the horse: The true mathematical model is the relativistic quantum mecha nical model where the wave is a probability distribution wave.Back in history de Broglie hit on a projection of the present theory  that happens to have the same variables as the correct quantum mechanical with l special relativity  models ( dirac and klein gordon equations). The de Broglie matter wave does not exist as far as present physics knowledge goes.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'm not at a very high level in physics, but I aspire to be. I'm a mathematician at heart and I hope one day I will understand all this new special relativity stuff. The thing is that the curriculum in our country still includes the de Broglie wave as part of quantum mechanics but it's taught at a very low level anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In the original non-relativistic formulation of wave mechanics by Schrödinger, his waves did indeed travel faster than light, and in fact their velocity was infinite. The propagator which showed the influence of one space time point on another clearly allowed superliminal influences.

His theory had other problems as well: his waves were unstable under the motion of the observer. Even at a slow walk, a zero-momentum wave (flat) suddenly morphed into a real wave. These problems were probably among the reasons he initially decided not to publish the theory.

Answer (score 0):

the book presents de broglie
λ=h/p
in classical form.
in classical mechanics there is no limit for speed.
once you insert the relativistic energy:
E=mc^2+(p^2 c^2)^2
you see that matter waves can not travel faster than light.

Answer (score -3):

No massive particle known exceeds the speed of light.
Matter waves (water waves, sound waves) and gravity waves are different, as are Electromagnetic waves.

Oh, de Broglie, this will give the wavelength of light (which has no mass keeping the problem easier). For massive particles we are getting into quantum mechanics (as stated in book) in which every particle is described by a wave function. 
Now it's true that there has indeed been evidence of "quantum teleportation" that exceeds the speed of light. 
I didn't come across it described in this way before. 
The mass of the particle itself is not in evidence travelling at the speed of light, it is wave-function collapse - a multi-state distributed wave-particle somehow resolving to a single state local interaction instantaineously when observed. Problem is it could be observed anywhere within it's distribution - (QM is weird, I can't hope to cover it here). 
Quantum-relativity hasn't been resolved as far as I'm aware, so work is ongoing. (I'm wondering what comes after the word "actually", tbh, we should probably not take the para out of context - perhaps the author is just trying to bring in QM step by step.) I might call it a wave-particle probably not a matter wave.

Comment: " Quantum-relativity hasn't been resolved ", what are you talking about?  Special relativity is  the mainstream quantum physics, within the mathematics of quantum mechanics. And de Broglie is about particles behaving as probability waves, not light.

Comment: Quantum gravity

Comment: I think the satement that "matter waves travel faster than light" is misleading at best. Matter = some energy.
And, as you note - there remains the question of gravity.